# Don't know how to use SetActive() properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

So, my script that I've written isn't working fully. I have A pause button and when I press it, it triggers my bool and shows that its working properly but when I'm "Paused" my UI doesn't pop up and my game doesn't stop in the back ground. I hope you can understand clearly. I am a beginner!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PauseManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject pauseMenu;

    public bool paused = false;

    public void start()
    {
        pauseMenu.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void update()
    {
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("escape"))
        {
            paused = !paused;
        }
        if (paused)
        {
            pauseMenu.SetActive(true);
            Time.timeScale = 0;

        }
        if (!paused)
        {
            pauseMenu.SetActive(false);
            Time.timeScale = 1;
        }

    }
    public void Resume()
    {
        paused = false;
    }
    public void pauseButton()
    {
        paused = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Advice you change your code to this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PauseManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject pauseMenu;

    bool paused = false;

    void Start()
    {
        pauseMenu.SetActive(false);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("escape"))
        {
            paused = !paused;
        }
        if (paused)
        {
            PauseGame();

        }
        if (!paused)
        {
            ResumeGame();
        }

    }
    void PauseGame(){
        pauseMenu.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = 0f;

    }

    void ResumeGame(){
        pauseMenu.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 1f;

    }
    public void Resume()
    {
        ResumeGame();
    }
    public void pauseButton()
    {
        PauseGame();
    }


}
```

I think the problem is on that when you **pause button** pressed, timescale be 0, and update does not work.

Comment: @ZacharyTurner There is a long way to walk in this road. Let us encourage each other in our endeavours.  ^_^